# Pre-selected item is not displaying in the ui-select-match value

Tags: angularjs

I have used LimitTo filter in ui-select where i have millions of items in my dropdown. So preselected items are not visible in select-match

[pre-selected item in dropdown is not populated, when reopen the window and item is not in filtered 100 items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7AsZ.png)

[Preselected item is populated when the item is in filtered 100 list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6VRE.png)

[when no item is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PGfy.png)

I used remove-selected="false" but no use.
can somebody help me out.

My code is

```
 <div class="form-group" id="locations-named-list">
            <label translate="yes">NamedList</label>
            <ui-select ng-model="selectedNamedList.name" theme="bootstrap" ui-select-no-animate
                on-select="updateSelectedNamedList($item)">
                <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices style="max-height: 140px !important;" repeat="t.name as t in namedLists | propsFilter: {name: $select.search} | limitTo: 100" position="down">
                    <div ng-bind-html="t.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should add all relevant code into your question instead of images and/or links.

Comment: Can you check now